# Javascript inside PHP browser detection

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Can anyone tell me why I keep getting the `else` and `alert` is not being triggered at all? The cookie is being set just while the browser is open.

```
<?php
$setcookie = setcookie('version', 'nova');
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
    if(!isset($setcookie)){
        if($browser["MSIE"] < 8.0){
        // display message or alert!

               echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n"; 
               echo 'alert("Please upgrade to version 8.0+ in order to view this site.");';
               echo "</script>";
        }
       }

        else

        {
            echo "Browser is current:";
        }

?>
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What does `$browser` contain? Do a `print_r($browser);` and post the results here (if they don't answer your question already)

Comment: try to use `< 8` instead of `8.0` and do a var_dump($browser) instead of the print_r to see what var type it will return.

Comment: print_r returns nothing. var_dump returns bool(false). thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` condition is wrong. You want to check the `$_COOKIE` array, not the return value of `setcookie`.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['version'])) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `get_browser()` returns what you think it returns? See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

You want to look at the `[browser]` and `[version]` fields.

Answer (score 1):

PHP get_browser() method is very slow. Better use something like

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

then you can do some preg_match as below

```
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$useragent)){
    //echo something here
}
else{
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: still showing browser is current. how blinking hard can this be. obviously my if logic is wrong somewhere but i cannot see it. thanks

Comment: is this correct for browser version in your code? if(preg_match('/MSIE 7.0/i',$useragent)) thanks

Comment: depends on what output $useragent gives. you will need to escape space as MSIE\ 7.0

Comment: this is what i am using. if(preg_match('/MSIE\ 7.0/i',$useragent)) is there a way to test for different versions. ie6/7/8 etc. thanks

Comment: Test $useragent output on different browsers, look for pattern ie6/ie7/ie8. I am sure a little bit of googling will get you what you want.